# What's the name of a person doing assurance

Tags: single-word-requests

This has come to my mind,

person doing test is a tester, person doing development is a developer, person doing consultation is a consultant, etc. My question, as written on the title, is, what's a person doing an assurance? If you need it more specific, what's a person doing a software quality assurance.

Comment: You mean like someone who does QA?

Comment: exactly... I forgot to add the 'quality' word

Comment: [assurer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assurer) is acceptable by M-W standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone who does Software Quality Assurance (SQA) would likely be called a [software quality analyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_analyst):

> A Software Quality Analyst is responsible for applying the principles and practices of software quality assurance throughout the software development life cycle.
>   The role of a software quality analyst is often confused with the software testing role. Most software companies designate software testing as software quality assurance, whereas these roles are different. Software Testing is product oriented, Software Quality Assurance is process oriented.

Comment: sadly, I'm one of the people thinking that doing testing means doing assurance as well...

Comment: @zfm I don't think there's a "right" answer about testing vs. assurance. It probably depends on the organization.

Comment: is software quality analyst same as software analyst?

Comment: @zfm I don't think so, but I'm not an expert on job titles.

Comment: @zfm Not normally. A software quality analyst would look at software which had already been written, analysing its quality; a software analyst [I'm one] analyses the requirement in order to write it in the first place.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: so it's like before and after... Thx

Comment: @zfm: Testing is one aspect of quality assurance, but not the only one. Software can work but be poorly written, or not comply with organizational standards, which an SQ analyst might catch. Moreover, an SQ analyst might analyze the quality of other artifacts as well, such as the design, or the documentation.